# Python Tkinter canvas inside canvas

Tags: python, tkinter

The docs suggest I should be able to position a  Frame object inside a Canvas, and that that Frame object could itself contain a Canvas. I'm wondering why the following toy code does not work. I don't see the the string "hello" anywhere, just the blue "outercanvas". What am I doing wrong?

```
from tkinter import *
class MainWindow(Frame):
def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()
    self.pack(fill=Y, side = LEFT)
    inframe = Frame(self)
    innercanvas = Canvas(inframe, width=20, height=20)
    innercanvas.create_text(10, 10, anchor=NW, text="Hello")

    outercanvas = Canvas(self, width=100, height=100, bg='#00ffff')
    outercanvas.create_window(0, 0, anchor=NW, window=inframe)
    outercanvas.pack(side=LEFT)

root = MainWindow()
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The primary reason why you're not seeing `innercanvas` is that you never called `.pack()` (or another geometry manager) on it, so the containing `inframe` doesn't know to display it.

Fixing that didn't actually make the code work, and I found this rather surprising - apparently, since you created `inframe` earlier than `outercanvas`, as children of the same Frame, `inframe` remained layered underneath the canvas and was therefore not visible.  (This was with Python 2.7, perhaps it's been fixed in the version you're using.)  Moving the creation of `outercanvas` up a few lines fixes this; you might perhaps want to make `inframe` a child of `outercanvas` instead of a sibling, to better reflect the hierarchical structure of your widgets.

Note that `inframe` is not actually needed at all - you could have used `create_window()` to directly add `innercanvas` to `outercanvas`.

Comment: What a fool! I can't believed I missed that. Thx

Answer (score 2):

```
from tkinter import *

class MainWindow(Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.pack(expand=Y,fill=BOTH)

        outercanvas = Canvas(self, width=200, height=100, bg='#00ffff')
        outercanvas.pack(expand=Y,fill=BOTH)

        innercanvas = Canvas(outercanvas, width=100, height=50)
        outercanvas.create_window(50, 25, anchor=NW, window=innercanvas)

        innercanvas.create_text(10, 10, anchor=NW, text="Hello")

root = MainWindow()
root.mainloop()
```

This canvas inside canvas works for me!